# Featured image from an embedded Vimeo video in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, vimeo

I have been trying to adapt [this script](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25808/setting-a-posts-featured-image-from-an-embedded-youtube-video) for vimeo with no results. I don't want to use a plugin, just a script to add in functions.php who works only for Vimeo and Youtube.

I can get the url image with:

```
$hash = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/'. $vimeo_id .'.php')); 
echo $hash[0]['thumbnail_large'];}
```

But I don't know how to take this and introduce it in "$vimeo_thumb_url"

```
function set_vimeo_as_featured_image($post_id) {   

    // only want to do this if the post has no thumbnail 
    if(!has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) {  

        // find the vimeo url 
        $post_array = get_post($post_id, ARRAY_A); 
        $content = $post_array['post_content']; 
        $vimeo_id = get_vimeo_id($content); 

        // build the thumbnail strings 

        $vimeo_thumb_url = ''; 

        // next, download the URL of the vimeo image 
        media_sideload_image($vimeo_thumb_url, $post_id, 'Sample vimeo image.'); 

        // find the most recent attachment for the given post 
        $attachments = get_posts( 
            array( 
                'post_type' => 'attachment', 
                'numberposts' => 1, 
                'order' => 'ASC', 
                'post_parent' => $post_id 
            ) 
        ); 
        $attachment = $attachments[0]; 

        // and set it as the post thumbnail 
        set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachment->ID ); 

    } // end if 

} // set_vimeo_as_featured_image 
add_action('save_post', 'set_vimeo_as_featured_image'); 

function get_vimeo_id($content) { 

    // find the vimeo-based URL in the post 
    $urls = array(); 
    preg_match('#http://(?:\w+.)?vimeo.com/(?:video/|moogaloop\.swf\?clip_id=)(\w+)#i', $content, $urls); 
    // next, locate the vimeo video id 
    $vimeo_id = ''; 
    if(strlen(trim($vimeo_url)) > 0) { 
        parse_str( parse_url( $vimeo_url, PHP_URL_QUERY ) ); 
        $vimeo_id = $v; 
    } // end if 

        return $vimeo_id;  

} // end get_vimeo_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get image link by doing this:

```
$hash = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$video_id.php"));
$src = $hash[0]['thumbnail_large'];
```

Hash array include src to images of different size. Just choose, what you need.